# Execute linux command through PHP

Tags: php, shell, command

I am using the tool for language analysis called Freeling. For language identification I use the `analyzer` command in the Linux console:

```
analyzer -f /usr/share/freeling/config/ident.cfg --outlv ident --fidn /usr/share/freeling/common/lang_ident/ident.dat
```

When I execute this command, its wait for the text entries (sentences) and determine what language they are in.
When I write a line of text in Spanish: "la casa es azul" and I press the enter key returns ES which means that it is written in Spanish. If I write "the house is blue" it returns EN, for the English language. To interrupt its execution press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

When I execute this command in the Linux console the first sentence takes some time to respond and the other times responds quickly.

I use this code to execute this php command but it takes many seconds to return the result:

```
<?php
$cmd = "analyzer -f /usr/share/freeling/config/ident.cfg --outlv ident --fidn /usr/share/freeling/common/lang_ident/ident.dat";

$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
    2 => array("pipe", "w"),
);

$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

$oracion[0]="we are the word";
$oracion[1]="somos el mundo";

if (is_resource($process)) {

    fwrite($pipes[0], $oracion[0]);
    fwrite($pipes[0], $oracion[1]);
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    while($pdf_content = fgets($pipes[1]))
    {
    echo $pdf_content . "<br>";
    }
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $return_value = proc_close($process);

}
?>
```

How can I improve the response time?

Comment: Shouldn't you at least send a newline with each sentence? And read the language response right after each? (Instead of senting two sentences first. Isn't that how it works on the command line?)

Comment: Try profiling execution or at least print time difference on each significant line to know where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Mario, you are right in what he says of the new line (\n) at the end of the sentence. I already did it and it continues slow.
I also tried to send the senetnces and then read the result and the execution is still very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the program, it needs to load the statistical models for all languages. That's why the first sentence takes longer.

The "analyzer" program provided with FreeLing is just a demo. The best way to use the library is to write your own program, as shown in FreLing tutorial  https://talp-upc.gitbooks.io/freeling-tutorial/content/

If you want to call FreeLing from PHP, there is no API, so you should probably resort to "server mode", where freeling is loaded once, and then it will accept requests.

You'll find more information in FreeLing user manual https://talp-upc.gitbooks.io/freeling-4-1-user-manual/content/

Comment: The first thing I tried was to execute the language identification in the server mode. 

I tried with the configuration file of the Spanish language

analyzer -f /usr/share/freeling/config/es.cfg --outlv ident --fidn /usr/share/freeling/common/lang_ident/ident.dat --server --port 12345

when I query the server with:

analyzer_client 12345 <texto.txt

the result is:

Server not ready?

Comment: If I tried with the language identification configuration file:

analyzer -f /usr/share/freeling/config/ident.cfg --outlv ident --fidn /usr/share/freeling/common/lang_ident/ident.dat --server --port 12345

analyzer_client 12345 <texto.txt

The result is always:

Server not ready?

Comment: Uhm you are right, there seems to be a bug in the analyzer that causes that the server does not work for lang ident.

Comment: I just fixed the bug.  If you download the file src/main/sample_analyzer/main.cc from gitHub and rebuild freeling, you'll have a server working for lang_ident.

You were lucky I checked SO just the day after you posted this. If you post this kind of questions in FreeLing forum, I will be able to answer sooner.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!!! I will try what it says.
About a week ago, try to subscribe to the freeling forum. After filling out the form I received the message that will await the approval of my request. I did not receive anything in my email .

Comment: Today I tried again to subscribe to the forum with the same name username and email and it gives me the error that has already been used. Then I receive for the first time in my mail:
Thank you for registering at FreeLing Home Page. Your application for an account is currently pending approval. Once it has been approved, you will receive another e-mail containing information about how to log in, set your password, and other details.

Comment: I hope that another email arrives with the approval. I would like very much to be able to write any questions directly in the freeling forum.

Comment: I just approved your registration. You should be getting the email now.

Comment: After downloading the files: main.cc and analyzer_client.cc and compiling the freeling works perfectly well. Thank you very much Lluis Padro !!